# How to set global options / parameters in Circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, parameters, options

I use Circuitikz quite often with modified sizing as styles as follows:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[line width=0.7pt, line join=round]
\draw (0,0)
...
to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=22pt, L] (1,0)
\end{circuitikz}
```

Is there a way to set global parameters such that I don't have to add the custom line width, join, and capacitor/inductor size each instance? I have tried adding them after "american" in `\usepackage[american,...]{circuitikz}` but it does not work. Thank you very much.

Comment: for example, put in preamble `\ctikzset{tripoles/op amp/height=1.6,
          tripoles/op amp/width =2.0}`

Comment: @Zarko When I do that with `inductor` instead of `op amp`, an error message appears: `Package pgfkeys: I do not know they key /tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/inductor/height`...

Comment: i just give an example, for your elements you had to use correct code (see in `circuitikz` manual, there is plenty examples) for global setting is dedicated `\ctikzset{...}`.

Comment: Sometimes the pfgkeys names are not what you might expect.  There is cuteinductor, americaninductor, vcuteinductor and vamericaninductor.  Not sure where european inductors get their height.